# Xrandr doesn't show my hdmi at all

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

This is my xrandr output

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 350mm x 220mm
   1920x1200     59.88*+
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1920x1080     59.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

and my sudo lshw -c video

```
<pre>*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Alder Lake-P GT1 [UHD Graphics]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 0c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:155 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I know for sure that the port is working because while booting the manifacturer screen shows up. But when the system is loaded hdmi screen disappears.

Comment: You're running with wayland, not xorg. xrandr is a command for xorg.

Comment: Thank you i don't have much knowledge about these technologies. While my computer is booting and the manifacturer screen is on displau my hdmi works but when os is loaded and ubuntu lock screen is on, my hdmi stops working. What may be the reason for that.